# SQL Developer connection to Exasol DB

Tags: connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, exasolution

How can I connect SQL Developer to an Exasol DB? Is this possible? 
I tried to download the Exasol driver but is not recognized by the SQL Developer.

Comment: You should show what code you tried

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not supported. SQL Developer's 3rd party JDBC connectivity is provided for one use case - migrations to Oracle Database.

There's no support on that for Exasol DB, so there's no connectivity support provided.

If you want a generic jdbc db client, that's not Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: That's not what I hoped to hear :) . But I tried many possibilities to add the exasol jdbc driver into SQL Developer and I didn't get it work, so I expected that. Thanks a lot for you answer and time.